# CreateReadStream is not a function

Tags: graphql, apollo, strapi

Hi I'm trying to upload a file using GraphQL and I'm getting the following error

```
Error: GraphQL error: createReadStream is not a function
    at new ApolloError (bundle.esm.js:63)
    at Object.next (bundle.esm.js:1004)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:135)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:179)
    at SubscriptionObserver.next (Observable.js:235)
    at bundle.esm.js:866
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.next (bundle.esm.js:866)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:135)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:179)
```

The following is my mutation

```
mutation UploadProfile($file: Upload!) {
  upload(file: $file) {
    id
  }
}
```

And the following is how I post my image

```
client.mutate<UploadProfile, UploadProfileVariables>({
        mutation: UploadProfileMutation,
        variables: {
          file: profileProperties.file,
        },
        context: {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        },
      })
```

I don't know why it's not working and I'm not finding the solution on the internet. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I was supposed to use the createUploadLink from the apollo-upload-client package instead of the Httplink

Comment: I am also getting same error while uploading the document using GraphQL. Can you please help me?